# Adding a 'like' button in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have made a little fiddle of what I am doing, although it won't work in fiddle oddly, but does incrementally add a like in my version: http://jsfiddle.net/LQFrv/

```
function($scope) {

var hasLiked = false;

$scope.likeClicked = function() {

    if( hasLiked === false ){
        $scope.likeCount = $scope.likeCount + 1;
    }

    hasLiked = true;

    if (hasLiked === true) {
        $scope.liked = 'Unlike';
    }

};
```

});

What I am trying to do is: Add a 'like' > disable 'like' and replace with 'unlike' > on next click of element, remove the like

Please help!

Thanks,

JP

Comment: use a browser console to look at errors. Fiddle immediately throws error `SyntaxError: function statement requires a name` and you have no `ng-controller` in fiddle html. What is the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML:

```
<body ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl"> 
    <a ng-click="likeClick()" ng-init="liked='Like'; likeCount=0">
        {{liked}} {{likeCount}}
    </a>
</body>
```

JS:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
var hasLiked = false;
$scope.likeClick = function () {
    if (!hasLiked) {
        hasLiked = true;
        $scope.liked = 'Unlike';
        $scope.likeCount += 1;
    } else {
        hasLiked = false;
        $scope.liked = 'Like';
        $scope.likeCount -= 1;
    }
};
```

}

Working fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/LQFrv/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/LQFrv/4/)
Hope that helps!

**edit:** messed up with the link, it lead to another fiddle, sorry, now it should be correct!

Comment: Thanks, I can't get the fiddle working, but will add that to my code now and see how it goes! Good work, quick response, I like!!

Comment: @JohnRobertPett sorry, I messed up the link, try again now!

Comment: Yeah, put that in my code already, good work! Thanks very much again for that!